# Building other matrices from these ones

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, concatenation

First of all, I want to know if it is possible to make a constraint in a set of matrices that I have to obtain a subset. For example, if I have a set of square matrices `A`, can I build a set `B` formed by the elements of `A` that has no null determinant?

If the answer is yes, I would like do do the following.

With

```
m = Table[Table[1, {4}], {3}]
S = ReplacePart[m, #] & /@ Thread[Rest[Subsets@Position[m, 1]] -> -1]
MatrixForm /@ S
Length@S
```

We obtain from

```
m={{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

the set of all matrices like `m` but changing the 1's to -1's. Now I want to add the line `{1,1,1,1}` to each matrix of the set `S` and obtain a set `S1`. Then I want to know how can I obtain the subset `M` of `S1` formed by all matrices that have no null determinant.

The final effect of what I am trying to achieve is to obtain the set of all `4 x 4` invertible matrices with entries `1` or `-1` and with the first line `{1,1,1,1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task in the last paragraph of your question can simply be achieved by the following:

```
Select[UnequalTo[0]@*Det]@Map[Prepend[{1, 1, 1, 1}]]@Tuples[{1, -1}, {3, 4}]
```

We first generate all possible $3\times 4$ matrices with `1`/`-1` as entries using [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html), then we add the row of `1`s using [`Prepend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prepend.html), and finally we select those that are invertible using [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

For your general question, I think [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) is what you're after.

Comment: It says "prepend called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected"

Comment: In that case your version of Mathematica is probably too old - You can replace `Prepend[{1,1,1,1}]` with `Prepend[#,{1,1,1,1}]&` to fix it by building the operator form "by hand "

Answer (score 1):

Probably less efficient than Mathe172's answer, but with simpler logic:

```
Select[Tuples[{1, -1}, {4, 4}], Det[#] =!= 0 && #[[1]] == {1, 1, 1, 1} &]
```

This generates all 4x4 matrices with +/-1 entries, then selects all those with Det not zero and with the specified first row.